# Implementing social sign-up to a complex registration form

Tags: forms, signup-signon, facebook-connect

I am working on a ticket to research & implement social sign-up to an already complex form. The registration form is currently 2 pages long & requires users to opt-in or out of newsletter subscriptions, which is a big business goal.

The problem I am having: by introducing a one-click social sign-up, the user will skip the 2nd page of the registration form and skip the newsletter subscriptions which are important to the business.

I wondered if anyone has worked on something similar and what the best practice would be to entice users to subscribe to newsletters later on in the journey?

Comment: Do you have a basic wireframe? I recently completed something similar for a client, where they had some specific details they wanted to collect. So I broke this into 3 sections, that would easily guide the user through the process and include some simple onboarding on the right as things progressed. The main thing to consider here is that it was for an employment agency, where the user wanted to complete the process.

Comment: Please add a wireframe or be more specific about what the form contains.There is not enough information to go on here.

Answer (score 1):

You could just after the login, when user is redirected to "dashboard" or any other beginning screen - display notices (similiar or same place where system messages are) at the very top with options to sign up. 
You could communicate it nicely - "Can we send you interesting news two times per month" and instead of classic checkbox place two buttons - "Accept" and "Decline". 
 Accept button should be in primary / dominant color, decline in secondary / neutral.